# How to normalization params when use tensorflow to inference

Tags: tensorflow

I'm study tensorflow,for example,I have a array contains 1~10000 linear number to be a train data,before I train data I normalization this array like below

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
data_array = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data_array)
```

now,I get a model,but how to use this model to inference? my app user input a param maybe 20000,how should I normalize 20000？

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple normalization formula :

1. Calculate the min and max from your data. Min=1 and max=20000
2. For every element in the array, which is suppose 'x' , subtract the min and divide the answer by max -min
3. The formula : x( new ) = x( old ) - min / max - min

Refer [here](https://medium.com/@equipintelligence/normalization-of-crazy-data-python-4fa6611e7b46).